# NULL elements are ignored for "column = ANY(array)"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query

```
select * from table1 where column1=ANY(@some_array)
```

`@some_array` - parameter that has array of values. It could contain null, which is correct according to my business logic.

Unfortunately, query returns nothing if `@some_array=[1, NULL]`

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-ANY-SOME) says:

> ```
> expression operator ANY (array expression)
> ```
>
> if the right-hand array contains any null elements and no true comparison result is obtained, the result of `ANY` will be null, [...]

But in my case the table contains values for 1 and for NULL, so the result must appear.

Does anybody understand why `select * from table1 where column1=ANY([1,NULL])` doesn't return data?

Comment: I think your doc reference already answers *why "select \* from table1 where column1=ANY([1,NULL])" doesn't return data*. Am I right to assume the actual question is now *how to otherwise search using null-containing arrays, for possibly null values*?

Comment: You will compare values with some comparision operator (`=`, `<=`, `<`, ...), so NULL will never be a match, no matter whether on the left-hand side or the right-hand side of the comparison. Both `null = ANY(array[1,2,3])` and `3 = ANY(array[1,2,null])` will result in null (i.e. unknown), because it is "not known" what the null may represent. When there is a match e.g. `1 = ANY(array[1,2,null])` then the result is TRUE, but when there is no match and there is a null in the array, the result will be NULL: This is what the documentation is trying to say.

Comment: I don't see why:`select 1 = ANY('{1, NULL}'::int[]); t`. This needs more information: 1) The type of `column1` 2) The type of `@some_array` 3) Example input and expected output. **Add as text output to question text**.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_position()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#id-1.5.8.25.6.2.2.8.1.1.1) instead. Internally, it uses [`is not distinct from`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE) comparison predicate instead of regular equality.
[Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/n4XPAfCK)

| id | column1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| *null* | *null* |

```
select * from table1 where column1=ANY(array[2,3,null]);
```

| id | column1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |

```
select * from table1 where array_position(array[2,3,null],column1) is not null;
```

| id | column1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| *null* | *null* |

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [`IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html) syntax (the usual one used to do a null-aware comparison) cannot be used with [`ANY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-ANY-SOME) in Postgres.

You can always transform  an `[NOT] IN` or `[=/<>] ANY` query into a [`[NOT] EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS).

So combine that with `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`.

```sql
select *
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1
    from (values(2),(3),(null)) a(value)
    where a.value is not distinct from t1.column1
);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/ojz4XH4T)

Comment: It looks like [this performs worse](https://dbfiddle.uk/45SYei_p). Lenghtening the search list to [200](https://dbfiddle.uk/LaRuYEQw) elements, then a [1000](https://dbfiddle.uk/_WcSzVZ2) amplifies that. Switching from `values` to `unnest()` that can accept the array directly could save some modifying of how `@some_array` is passed around, but it seems to add another performance penalty ([1](https://dbfiddle.uk/ks7MthBD), [2](https://dbfiddle.uk/AoypV_yF), [3](https://dbfiddle.uk/vZKy-y3H)).